# Create MediaStream from Hls.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, html5-audio, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I have a HLS stream that I am attaching to an audio element using the [Hls.js library](https://hls-js.netlify.app/demo/). I want to then take that stream and feed it into [Wave.js](https://foobar404.dev/Wave.js/docs/). I want to use the `fromStream` method to construct the audio waveform visualiser and not `fromElement` so that I can set the optional `connectDestination` argument to false.

For creating the media stream that is fed into the `Wave.fromStream()` constructor, I am following [this example](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/video-video/) that shows how `captureStream()` can be used to mirror the playback of an audio or video element.
My implementation of capturing the stream is as follows.

```
  let audio = this.audioPlayer.nativeElement;
  let stream;
  if (audio.captureStream) {
    stream = audio.captureStream();
  } else if (audio.mozCaptureStream) {
    stream = audio.mozCaptureStream();
  } else {
    console.error('Stream capture is not supported');
    stream = null;
  }
```

Stream is then passed into Wave.fromStream().

Unfortunately, when Wave.fromStream() is executed, I get the following error.

```
core.js:6498 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'createMediaStreamSource' on 'AudioContext': MediaStream has no audio track
```

This means that the media stream passed into Wave.fromStream, has no audio tracks associated with it. And when I look at my audio element, even with the Hls stream attached to it, logging Audio.audioTracks returns undefined, even though there is a stream of audio playing and being controlled by that audio element. So there is no issue with creating the media stream from the audio element, it is just how Hls.js is attaching the stream to the audio element.

Is there another way to create a media stream object from a Hls stream created by Hls.js?

Comment: Is your stream encrypted by chance?  Are you sure `nativeElement` is the right element?

Comment: This is how I am accessing my audio element from my typescript `@ViewChild("audioPlayer") audioPlayer: ElementRef;` I then use `let audioEl = this.audioPlayer.nativeElement` to access things like the ply/pause/mute functions for my custom audio player. Every other mechanism I use to interact with the audio player is through native element, inlcuding when I use Hls.attachMedia() to attach the Hls object to the audio element. As for the encryption, I am not sure. Though I dont see why that would impact the audio tracks seen in the audio element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem which was to create my own customised version of the @foobar404/wave npm package and modify it to accept an input argument which is a pre existing audio context and the final node in the context. this means that I can connect the waveform to the final node in the audio context without then connecting the waveform to the audio context destination or source which is where my errors were coming from.

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wave-external-audio-context